# powershell code that first checks the service on server and displays server name service name and boot type

Tags: powershell, service, server

how can i write a powershell code that first checks the service on server and displays server name service name and boot type! then if it is on automatic, it switches manually and efer it shows the status again

```
$servicename = 'spooler'
$server = 'server2'      
$G$GetStatus= Get-Service -DisplayName $servicename -ComputerName $server | Select-Object -ExpandProperty StartType
Write-host "$GetStatus" -ForegroundColor red 
Write-host "$servicename på $server" -ForegroundColor Green

if ($GetStatus.StartType -eq 'Automatic') {
$GetStatus | Set-Service -StartupType Manual
}
}
}
Write-output "$GetStatus" -ForegroundColor red 
Write-output "$servicename på $server" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Comment: when you run this bit of code `Select-Object -ExpandProperty StartType` you **_throw out_** everything _except_ the value of the specified property. [*grin*] that means your `$GetStatus.StartType -eq 'Automatic'` will **_fail_** since the `.StartType` property no longer exists. ///// plus, when you run this `$GetStatus | Set-Service -StartupType Manual` there is no reference to the service OR the server ... only the value that was in the `.StartType` property. ///// a good habit to get into is DO NOT REMOVE  OR EXPAND PROPERTIES unless you **_need_** to do so. [*grin*]

Comment: but how can I have something that shows status first for server name service and startup type then changes the startup type ?!

Comment: another point ... you are using `spooler` for `.DisplayName` but that is NOT the display name for that service. that is the `.Name` while the `.DisplayName` is `Print Spooler`.

Comment: you do that by using the properties in the full object, not the stripped down _value_ of one property of the object. [*grin*] take a look at the properties of the original object [after you correct the displayname/name error in your code].

Comment: Yes. i now! i kan fix it!

Comment: Kan you write one exemple code!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's an example of what i mean by NOT throwing out the object in favor of one value from one property of the object.

```
$servicename = 'spooler'
$server = 'LocalHost'

$ServiceInfo = Get-Service -Name $servicename -ComputerName $server

Write-host $ServiceInfo.StartType -ForegroundColor red 
Write-host "$servicename på $server" -ForegroundColor Green
''

if ($ServiceInfo.StartType -eq 'Automatic')
    {
    $ServiceInfo |
        Set-Service -StartupType Manual -WhatIf
    }

''
Write-output $ServiceInfo.StartType
Write-output "$servicename på $server"
```

output ...

```
Automatic
spooler på LocalHost

What if: Performing the operation "Set-Service" on target "Print Spooler (spooler)".

Automatic
spooler på LocalHost
```

i have not tested it on my system, but the `-WhatIf` seems to indicate it will work. i have only the one system to use ... and am unwilling to muck around with it. [*grin*]

notes ...

- kept the entire object instead of only the value of the `StartType` property
- addressed the desired property by its name `$ServiceInfo.StartType`
- used the entire object to tell `Set-Service` what to work on

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
$serviceName = "spooler"
$server = "server2"

Get-Service -Name $serviceName -ComputerName $server |
        ForEach-Object {}{
            $_ | Format-Table Name, Status, StartType -AutoSize

            if ($_.StartType -eq "Automatic")
            {
                Set-Service -InputObject $_ -StartupType Manual
            }
        }{Get-Service -Name $serviceName -ComputerName $server | Format-Table Name, Status, StartType -AutoSize}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

```
$server = 'server2'
$servicename = 'spooler'
$services = Get-Service -ComputerName $server -Name $servicename 
# show what was found 
Write-Host "`r`nService(s) named '$servicename' on '$server'" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$services | Format-Table DisplayName, Name, ServiceName, Status, StartType, MachineName -AutoSize

# next change the StartupType for any service found that is set to 'Automatic'
$services | Where-Object { $_.StartType -eq 'Automatic' } | ForEach-Object { 
    Write-Host "Setting StartupType for service '$($_.Name)' on computer '$($_.MachineName)' to 'Manual'" -ForegroundColor Green
    $_ | Set-Service -StartupType Manual }

# show what has changed
Get-Service -ComputerName $server -Name $servicename | 
Format-Table DisplayName, Name, ServiceName, Status, StartType, MachineName -AutoSize
```

If you do not know the exact name of the service, you may better use `Get-Service` with a partial name.
You can do this with the `like` operator. In that case, add asterikses around the servicename and 
change the lines `$services = Get-Service -ComputerName $server -Name $servicename` so it becomes:

```
$servicename = '*spooler*'
$services = Get-Service -ComputerName $server | Where-Object { $_.Name -like $servicename }
```